# How to get actual - not simulated - GPS signal into an Android simulator

Tags: android, gps, location, emulation

First of all, I am NOT interested in using simulated location - I need the actual real time position. I have a uBlox GPS receiver connected to a Windows 7 PC which gives NMEA sentences on COM3 in my case. The PC is running an Android simulator (BlueStacks). Is there any way of getting real time position from the uBlox GPS receiver to the Android emulator?

Comment: I was able to register the GPS receiver as a location sensor in Windows 7 using GPSComplete. This location doesn't seem to be properly passed to the Android emulator, though.

Comment: Have you managed to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No way you're going to get access to COM3 from emulated android... so...

You could write a utility or service on the host PC to update the "simulated" location via adb.

The ADB command: geo fix -82.411629 28.054553

You can either run an adb shell by wrapping the process of a launched instance of adb, or by sending telnet commands to localhost:5554.

Telnet requires a handshake sequence to start up. Not quite a straight socket. See the telnet RFCs for details. Not hard to do.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's a (now discontinued, but possible to find it if you look) Android emulator called DuOS which in the configuration under Device Settings has GPS tab and you can select the COM port there.